# How to find words from scrambled words

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, hash, tree

I'm trying to find a way to find specific words in scrambled text that appear consecutively. Characters that aren't found will have a `X` in place.

For example let's say the list of dictionary words are:

```
jane
john
brownbag
foo
youth
```

and scrambled text:

```
ofozlhuoyt => fooXXyouth
yuawbnrobgajen => XXbrownbagjane
janjeohn => (nothing since jane and john aren't consecutive)
```

**Approach I'm trying:**

Say, I have a hash with keys `a` through `z` with set as values for each key. Each number in the set will represent the index where of word that contains the particular character.

From above example:

```
{a: [0,2]}
{b: [2]}
{c: []}
{e: [0]}
{f: [3]}
{g: [2]}
{h: [1,4]}
{j: [0,1]}
...
{n: [0,1,2]}
{o: [1,2,3,4]}
{r: [2]}
{u: [4]}
{t: [4]}
{w: [2]}
{y: [4]}
...
{z: []}
```

After preparing the above, we can begin looking at each character of the scrambled text:

First String: `ofozlhuoyt`

1. o => exists in 1, 2, 3, and 4
2. start with 1: jane (length 4)
3. get 4 chars: `ofoz`
4. `"jane".sort(false) == "ofoz".sort(false)?`
5. if false: repeat steps 1 to 3 for 2 (john)
6. if true: add foo to list of good words and start step 0 with `z`

Is there a better way of doing this? I feel a better data structure exists to resolve something like this but I can't figure out which to use..

Comment: Very nice approach, I'm not sure that there is possibility to optimize it more from the logic point of view, maybe just sort dictionary words at the very start (there is no sense to sort them each time you compare), also if you store dictionary ID in asc order by word length - you can minimize amount of "ofoz" sort calls

Comment: You can build a state machine with a state transition table so that e.g. `j` goes to either `n` (could be jane or john), `ae` (could be jane), `oh` (could be john), or none of them, and so on.

Comment: How would I go about building that. Sounds like I'd need a tree structure.

Comment: I agree with @500-InternalServerError. A state machine is the right way to go here. Don't try implementing it on your own, though. It's ... complicated, to say the least. I have used [OpenFST](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome]) in the past, and quite liked it.

Comment: Could a Trie be used?

Comment: User @500-InternalServerError is describing a variant of the Aho-Corasick algorithm. Google should find what you need.

Comment: How large are your word lists, and how often do they change? Also, how long is a typical text string that you're going to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a potentially faster way, provided you have enough memory to implement it.

First, generate all the permutations for each word. So for "jane" you would have:

```
aejn
aenj
ajen
ajne
anej
anje
etc.
```

Then, build a state machine for the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), with each of the permutations for a single word going to the same ending state. That ending state would output the string you're looking for.

Now run the text through the state machine. The output would be the words that are found, and their positions. You can then sort the found words by position and determine if they appear consecutively.

The state machine is potentially very large (n! states for each word, where n is the number of characters in the word), and will take some time to build. But once it's built, it matches very quickly. If your word list is static and you have a lot of text to search, this is the way to go. Provided you have enough memory.

I used a modified Aho-Corasick algorithm that was searching text for occurrences of millions of phrases (band and song names) in video titles. The state machine occupied about 10 gigabytes of RAM and took about an hour to build, but it was *fast* when it came to matching.

Comment: The state machine will be non-deterministic, right? Because a given pattern could generate more than one word. E.g. `owh` could go to `who` or `how`.

Comment: @ChthonicProject: That's only a problem if the list of dictionary words includes anagrams. If it does, the problem is much harder.

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't thought of anagrams at first. It's your example which made me think of this issue (based on *jane* and *jean*).

Comment: @ChthonicProject: Come to think of it, if the list of dictionary words includes anagrams, then the problem doesn't have a single solution. You could modify my solution to output multiple words in a single output state. That wouldn't require changing the state machine, but rather changing the action that occurs when a match is found.

Comment: Yes, correct. It won't remain as fast as a DFA, but it will produce all the correct answers.

Comment: Downvoter? Something you'd like to share with the rest of us? It's customary to supply a reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use prime numbers!

When you multiply n prime numbers, the product you get will be different from any other **combination** of primes.

In your problem, the key is that order does not matter so **sorting will be a waste of time**. In other words,

```
'jane' == 'ejna' == 'jnea' == ...
```

So, you can create your own hash function based on the cool prime property, and use commutativity over multiplication to avoid sorting/string-searches altogether. And in python, you don't even have to worry about the size of ints; that will come in handy in case your dictionary has really big words.

Below is a simple dict mapping letters to the first 26 primes, and the accompanying hash function.

```
letters_to_primes = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 7, ... 'x': 89, 'y': 97, 'z': 101}

def my_prime_hash(word):
    sum = 1
    for letter in word:
        sum = sum * letters_to_primes[letter] # Multiplication is commutative!
    return sum
```

Again, the key property we're exploiting here is that

```
my_prime_hash('jane') == my_prime_hash('enaj') == ... == 27434
```

Now we simply need to create our dict of the given dictionary words. I propose an **external-chaining hash-table**. Let us call it 'hashed_words'.

```
# Given these words
words = ['jane', 'john', 'brownbag', 'foo', 'youth', 'nib', 'bin']

# Compute the hash table
hashed_words = {}
for word in words:
    w_hash = my_prime_hash(word)
    if w_hash in hashed_words: hashed_words[w_hash].append(word)
    else: hashed_words[w_hash] = [word]
```

After running it, hashed_words looks like:

```
{1113571: ['john'], 27434: ['jane'], 
 28717: ['foo'], 448956643: ['youth'], 
 3131090838L: ['brownbag'], 2967: ['nib', 'bin']}
```

which is what we want.

Now you can start hashing the scrambled word by computing the products of the letters and check at every point if the product is in hashed_words. A state machine like the one others have proposed is necessary for cases like 'mart' and 'smart' in the scrambled word 'mrtasgth' (see comments below).

Note: Instead of assigning prime numbers in ascending order, you could consider the frequency distribution of all the letters occurring in your dictionary and assign the lowest prime number to the letter with the highest frequency. This will indeed save memory while creating your 'hashed_words' hash table.

Comment: An interesting idea. It'd work for relatively small files. But run against a much longer string, that's going to take a very long time. Basically, you do on the order of `n*longest_string` lookups, where `n` is the text length and `longest_string` is the length of the string with the biggest hash. Also, given the search words `["mart", "smart"]`, your algorithm would find `"mart"` but fail to find `"smart"` when run against the string `"armts"`.

Comment: @JimMischel you are right that it will take n*longest_string lookups. But for the 'mart' and 'smart' problem, a state machine will do the job. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin–Karp_algorithm

which is very similar to the hash idea and related to the aho-corasick algorithm